# How to store a var count.name on Redis (where name is an arg)

Tags: python, redis

Redis is counting the number of hits on the root. I added a arg "name", my code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def hello(name):
    count = redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Hello {} I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(name,count)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
```

I want to store and return a different count that I wish to link to the "name" var. I was thinking about using an array, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is to store a json string that represents a dictionary of users and their counts, like this:

```
import json

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def hello(name):
    counts = json.loads(redis.get('hits') or '{}')
    try:
         counts[name] += 1
    except KeyError:
         counts[name] = 1
    redis.set('hits', json.dumps(counts))
    return 'Hello {} I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(name,counts[name])
```

Comment: Hi @burhan_khalid I don't understand this line  `counts = json.loads(redis.get('hits', '{}'))`. What the argument {} represents here ? It's retruning this error "TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am too used to the django interface for caching. I have updated the code.

Comment: I don't know lot about django so I don't see a difference. Could you please explain a bit ? Btw, I still having a smilar error " File "/app/app3.py", line 11, in hello
    counts = json.loads(redis.get('hits'),'{}')
TypeError: loads() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @burhan_khalid, I missed the 'or'  in the get fct in on your correction. But I think the count is not right, as I'm getting this error _counts[name] + 1 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable_ is we are not accessing the count but the object, I'm right ?